# How can I get more details about an exception that occurred in my application?

Tags: java, android, exception, stack-trace, line-numbers

I want to show details of an exception that occurred in my application, like the line number of the exception. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. There are lots of information about your exception in stackTraceElement in the following example.

customize this method:

```
private static String getExceptionDetails(Activity act, Exception e) {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement = e.getStackTrace();

    String fileName = "";
    String methodName = "";
    int lineNumber = 0;

    try {
        String packageName = act.getApplicationInfo().packageName;
        for (int i = 0; i < stackTraceElement.length; i++) {
            if (stackTraceElement[i].getClassName().startsWith(packageName))
            {
                fileName = stackTraceElement[i].getFileName();
                methodName = stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName();
                lineNumber = stackTraceElement[i].getLineNumber();
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
    }

    return fileName + ":" + methodName + "():line "
            + String.valueOf(lineNumber);
}
```

Comment: You can log the Exception and it will print the full stacktrace (what your method does but in 1 single line of code).

Comment: There are lots of information in stackTraceElement. He can customize it.

Answer (score 4):

```
exception.printStackTrace()
```

Shows line number and method name which has generated exception.

Comment: I mentioned that it is hard to get line number from this string separately.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check?

```
exception.printStackTrace()
```

Comment: it is hard to get line number from this string.

Comment: @pick unless you read the console you can't get the detail. This is the only way to do.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this:

```
public static String getStackTrace(Throwable throwable) {
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

  try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)) {
    throwable.printStackTrace(pw);
    return sw.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch block as

```
 try{

   // here add your code 

    }catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("error",e.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

check -

```
exception.getMessage()
```